# Regular expression for range 0-200.0000 (including 0 and 200)

Tags: regex, max, decimal

I'm trying to write regular expression that accepts number between `0` and `200.0000`.

I managed to write this for now:

```
^([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|200){1}(\.[0-9]{1,4})?$
```

But problem is that my expression accept numbers like `200.0001` and greater.

Any idea how to set limit on numbers after decimal point if number before is `200`? Thanks

Comment: It is due to `[0-9]{1,4}`. Use `0{1,4}`. If you want to match any numbers in the fractional part before `200`, you need to set two different optional groups for the `200` and the previous alternatives.

Comment: See `^(?:(?:[1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2})(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?|200(?:\.0{1,4})?)$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/MHjgoA/2)).

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) as you are entitled to the upvoting privilege after reaching 15 rep points. Note you may upvote all the answers that turned out helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `(\.[0-9]{1,4})?` matches an optional sequence of a dot and one through four *any* digits after `0`, `1`, `11`, `111` **and** `200`, too. You need to use `(\.[0-9]{1,4})?` for the numbers before `200` and `(\.0{1,4})?` for `200`.

```
^(?:(?:[1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2})(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?|200(?:\.0{1,4})?)$
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/MHjgoA/2)

I suggest using non-capturing groups rather than capturing ones (that is, convert `(...)` to `(?:...)`) as you are not going to use those parts later.

I see your pattern is [generated online](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/) automatically, so I decided to "shrink" it a bit.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group matching two alternatives:

  - `(?:[1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2})(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?`:

    - `(?:[1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2})` - an optional digit from `1` to `9` and then any 1 digit, or `1` followed with any two digits
    - `(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?` - an optional sequence of a dot followed with one through four *any* digits
  - `|` - or
  - `200(?:\.0{1,4})?` - `200` followed with 1 or 0 occurrences of `.` followed with 1 through 4 zeros
  - `)$` - end of group and string.